# SQLite, How to insert data into one table from two tables

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I'm doing some rental project in Java and SQLite and now I have 2 tables (my first SQLite project):

- ClientTable with ID, Name, LastName
- MovieTable with ID, Title,
  Director

and now I wanna make 3rd table RentalTable with ID, Name, LastName, Title.
So far I have something like this:

`String queryC = insert into RentalTable (Name, LastName) select Name, LastName from ClientTable where ID='"+textIdClient.getText()+"'`

I tried to make second query like:

`String queryM="insert into RentalTable  (Title) select Title from MovieTable where ID='"+textIdMovie.getText()+"' ";`

but it makes 2 rows. First with Name and Last Name and second with Title and I want just 1 row with Name, Last Name and Title.

Answer (score 0):

To get column values from multiple tables, use a join:

```sql
INSERT ...
SELECT c.Name,
       c.LastName,
       m.Title
FROM ClientTable AS c
JOIN MovieTable AS m
WHERE c.ID = ?
  AND m.ID = ?;
```

Comment: It's many-to-many relationship and I just found this:    "select * from ClientTable inner join RentalTable  on ClientTable .ID=RentalTable .ID_Client inner join ClientTable on RentalTable .ID_Movie=ClientTable .ID";